# if the data is null or empty, how can set dont show it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

if the data is null or empty, how can set dont show it?

when I get the print_data.chrt_B1_Measures is null or empty, how do I do dont show

?

```
<p style="margin-left: 28px">
    <span>Solution：</span>
<br />
    <span class="ql-editor" v-html="print_data.chrt_B1_Measures"></span>
</p>
```

is it use v-if then??

I'd tried to used this

```
<p style="margin-left: 28px" v-if="!print_data.chrt_B1_Measures">
    <span>Solution：</span>
<br />
    <span class="ql-editor" v-html="print_data.chrt_B1_Measures"></span>
</p>
```

But it's failed....

Comment: `v-if="!print_data.chrt_B1_Measures"` should be `v-if="print_data.chrt_B1_Measures"`. The `!` operator negates the operand; for a string, that checks if the string is falsy (null/undefined/empty). You effectively told Vue to show this paragraph if there is *no string data*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<p style="margin-left: 28px" v-show="print_data.chrt_B1_Measures">
    <span>Solution：</span>
<br />
    <span class="ql-editor" v-html="print_data.chrt_B1_Measures"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Why should OP _try this_? What did you change, what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create like this in computed:

```
total() {
    if (this.print_data) {
      if (this.print_data.chrt_B1_Measures) {
        return this.print_data.chrt_B1_Measures
      } else {
        return 0
      }
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }
```

and put this in your v-show condition

```
<p style="margin-left: 28px" v-show="!total">
```